# KDE System Tray Organizer

Tags: kde

Is it possible to organize order of icons or lock them in KDE system tray? It's very confusing with a lot of shuffled application icons.

Edit: Does anybody know where are system tray configuration files?

Comment: you can't lock them, but you can choose what is and isn't displayed.

Comment: Thanks @xenoterracide! I want something like MS Windows 7. In windows or (more or less) in Gnome, I can specify the location of each icon.

Comment: might want to bug plasma people. only settings I know available are in the system tray settings which is available by right clicking it (esp the area where you have hidden icons). I don't know what Windows 7 or Gnome does, I don't use either.

Answer (score 2):

The KDE system tray configuration files can be found at `~/.kde4/share/config/plasma-desktop-appletsrc`.

Comment: Thanks. Could you expand a bit on that answer? In particular, since that was the original purpose of the question: what to put/change in this file to reorganize icons?

Comment: In the current KDE5 the file is `~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but ....

On my kde (4.4.5 - kubuntu lucid) panel, I click on the cashew at the end.  When I do, it brings up a menu for customizing the panel.  While that menu is open, I can use the mouse to drag and drop any of my application icons to a new location on the panel.

Does this do what you want?

There does seem to be a limitation based on the size of the icons themselves.  The small ones are all clustered together in a quick launch area, but can be moved among themselves.

In the menu, there's a lock icons button, but I don't know what it does.

Comment: Not sure about the asker, but it answered my question about how to rearrange the icons on the system tray--and, I think many other questions, since I wasn't really conscious of the 'cashew' being part of the interface.

Comment: In the quick launch area, I set it to use 2 lines and that was what made the icons there small (which was what I wanted.)

Answer (score 0):

I personally recommend making a nice backup of the "plasma-desktop-appletsrc" file in case maybe by inserting some buggy widget something should go wrong.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).